# CentOS 7 (1503) - BIND9 new install not responding to external DNS requests

Tags: linux, centos, redhat, bind, named-conf

I am trying to set up an authoritative BIND server and every time I run into the same problem on CentOS. I can run the dig command locally for zones on the server however when I run `nslookup - serverip` from cmd.exe i get no response.

The firewall is open on the server and bind shows nothing in `/var/log/messeges` or in `/var/named/data/named.run`

Here is my /etc/named.conf

```
options {
listen-on port 53 { 127.0.0.1; 172.16.100.1; 1.1.1.1; };
//listen-on-v6 port 53 { ::1; };
directory   "/var/named";
dump-file   "/var/named/data/cache_dump.db";
statistics-file "/var/named/data/named_stats.txt";
memstatistics-file "/var/named/data/named_mem_stats.txt";
allow-query     { any; };
allow-transfer  { localhost; 172.16.100.67; };
recursion no;
dnssec-enable yes;
dnssec-validation yes;
dnssec-lookaside auto;
/* Path to ISC DLV key */
bindkeys-file "/etc/named.iscdlv.key";
managed-keys-directory "/var/named/dynamic";
pid-file "/run/named/named.pid";
session-keyfile "/run/named/session.key";
};
logging {
        channel default_debug {
                file "data/named.run";
                severity dynamic;
        };
};
zone "." IN {
    type hint;
    file "named.ca";
};
include "/etc/named/zones.conf";
include "/etc/named.rfc1912.zones";
include "/etc/named.root.key";
```

I have rebooted and disabled SELinux to eliminate it. I have checked the correct firewall settings are in place.

`named-checkconf /etc/named.conf` shows no errors and the service starts successfully, I can ping the server.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is your interface actually in the `public` firewalld zone? Use `firewall-cmd --get-active-zones` to check.

Comment: Yes, all my servers are in the public zone including this one. by default. Does this ever change unless set by an admin?

Comment: Not in CentOS/RHEL 7. But I could not safely assume an admin didn't change something.

Comment: Fortunately or unfortunately I am the only admin for our 500 servers >.<

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are testing this you are sending your queries to `172.16.100.66`.

Your `named.config` specifies the following addresses: `listen-on port 53 { 127.0.0.1; 172.16.100.67; 100.111.100.121; };`

Ie, I would expect that `named` is not listening on the address that you are sending the queries to.

Comment: THANKS! I have no idea why I always put the wrong setting in there. Up until now I had resorted to running all my bind server on ubuntu because I didn't seem to have this issue on that OS. Strange.

Comment: @AirCombat I'm not sure I understand what exactly you mean. `listen-on` will define which addresses that `named` binds to. Compare eg `netstat -plnut` output.